# Set boolean on object change Parse.com

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

**Situation:**

I have a database at Parse.com. In this database I have objects which have an Array and a boolean.

**Wanted Result:**

I want the boolean to be set to true if the Array length is bigger than 0. And false if the size is 0.

**Problem:**

I do not want to set this boolean on adding/deleting from array, but i want some kind of listener that reacts on a change to the object.

**A must**

This solution has to be possible with only cloud code.

---

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely and this can be easily accomplished using a [cloud code beforeSave hook](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers).

In the beforeSave of the desired class, look at the size of the array and set the bool accordingly. This will guarantee the bool is up-to-date for every save.

Here's some sample code

```
// Update the boolean based on the array length
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("yourClass", function(request, response) {

    var yourArray = request.object.get("yourArray");

    if (yourArray.length > 0) {
        request.object.set("booleanProperty", true);
    } else {
        request.object.set("booleanProperty", false);
    }
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: will this also count the item that I'm adding?

Comment: Yeah it will count the items you've added to the array before calling save